# Por que no me devuelve la información de mi query en laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Que tal tengo este problema, no se por que no me funciona, porque en otros modulos si funciona, es un resultado de un query.

esto es en controlador de laravel:

```
$reajuste = DB::table('reajuste as r')
                    ->join('tipo_ajuste as t','t.id_tipo_ajuste','r.id_tipo_ajuste')
                    ->where('r.id_reajuste','=',$id)
                    ->select('r.id_reajuste as id','t.id_tipo_ajuste as tipo')
                    ->get();
        return view('Reajustes.show',compact('reajuste'));
```

esto es en el blade:

```
<label for="descripcion">Descripcion</label>
                <input type="text" value="{{$reajuste->id}}" class="form-control" disabled="">
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: dale un dd($reajuste) y ves que campos te esta devolviendo!

Answer (score 3):

Si solo imprimes uno la función get() no es la que necesitas, en su caso utiliza first()

```
DB::table('reajuste')->tusConsultas()->first();
```

De otra manera estarás obteniendo un array de varios elementos

Comment: Gracias, cambie el get() por el first(), eso me sirvió